# plpgsql function concat optionnal args return error

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I want to concat optionnal arguments separated by AND and return a varchar of those concatenate argument(s) that are not null.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION shop_apply_search_filters(price_min INTEGER DEFAULT NULL, price_max INTEGER DEFAULT NULL, ecom_id  INTEGER DEFAULT NULL, 
                                                        cat_1 VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL, cat_2 VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL)
  RETURNS VARCHAR AS
$$
DECLARE final_filters VARCHAR(500);
BEGIN
    IF price_min IS NOT NULL THEN
        SELECT CONCAT('price<',price_min) AS n_price_min;
        final_filters := n_price_min;
    END IF;

    IF price_max IS NOT NULL THEN
        SELECT CONCAT('price>',price_max) AS n_price_max;
        final_filters := CONCAT(final_filters,' AND ', n_price_max);
    END IF;

    IF ecom_id IS NOT NULL THEN
        SELECT CONCAT('ecom_id=',ecom_id) AS n_ecom_id;
        final_filters := CONCAT(final_filters,' AND ', n_ecom_id);
    END IF;

    IF cat_1 IS NOT NULL THEN
        SELECT CONCAT('category_1:',cat_1) AS n_cat_1;
        final_filters := CONCAT(final_filters,' AND ', n_cat_1);
    END IF;

    IF cat_2 IS NOT NULL THEN
        SELECT CONCAT('category_2:',cat_2) AS n_cat_2;
        final_filters := CONCAT(final_filters,' AND ', n_cat_2);
    END IF;

    RETURN final_filters;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

The output of SELECT shop_apply_search_filters(10) would be a string like 'price > 10'.
Is it possible to pass args name when calling function ? In order to be able to distinguish price_min and price_max if only one of them is passed.
Is it possible to append not null args to a list and then JOIN list elements with an AND ?

How would you do ?

**EDIT**

I removed the SELECT() when CONCAT() to avoid error. But I have a new one :

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function shop_apply_search_filters(integer,integer,integer,character varying,character varying) line 5 at SQL statement
SQL state: 42601
```

**EDIT**
I tried :

```
create or replace function shop_apply_search_filters(
    price_min integer default null, 
    price_max integer default null, 
    ecom_id  integer default null, 
    cat_1 text default null, 
    cat_2 text default null)
returns text as
$$
    select concat_ws(
        ' and ',
        'price < '      || price_min,
        'price > '      || price_max,
        'ecom_id = '    || ecom_id,
        'category_1 = ' || cat_1,
        'category_2 = ' || cat_2
    );
$$
language sql;
```

It works fine with all arguments passed :

```
SELECT shop_apply_search_filters(10,10,10,'cat_1','cat_2')
```

How to handle when not all arguments are passsed ?

```
SELECT shop_apply_search_filters(10,10,'cat_1','cat_2')

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "cat_1"
LINE 1: SELECT shop_apply_search_filters(10,10,'cat_1','cat_2')
                                               ^
SQL state: 22P02
Character: 40

SELECT shop_apply_search_filters(10,10)
ERROR:  function shop_apply_search_filters(integer, integer) is not unique
LINE 1: SELECT shop_apply_search_filters(10,10)
               ^
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42725
Character: 8
```

Comment: There must be more going on because the function and the select as shown most definitely works: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3ae9ab42717dcd666c9ff4be6de2c88b  It seems you have several overloaded functions with that name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use `concat_ws()` to join the whole string at once?

```
concat_ws(
    ' and ',
    'price < '      || price_min,
    'price > '      || price_max,
    'ecom_id = '    || ecom_id,
    'category_1 = ' || cat_1,
    'category_2 = ' || cat_2
)
```

You could then simplify the whole procedure as:

```
create or replace function shop_apply_search_filters(
    price_min integer default null, 
    price_max integer default null, 
    ecom_id  integer default null, 
    cat_1 text default null, 
    cat_2 text default null)
returns text as
$$
    select concat_ws(
        ' and ',
        'price < '      || price_min,
        'price > '      || price_max,
        'ecom_id = '    || ecom_id,
        'category_1 = ' || cat_1,
        'category_2 = ' || cat_2
    );
$$
language sql;
```

Comment: It's not part of the immediate problem in the question, but: the function sounds as if it should create a condition to be used in a WHERE clause. In that case the values for `cat_1` and `cat_2` should probably be enclosed in single quotes, e.g. using `quote_literal()`. The individual conditions should probably be combined with AND as well.